# How to show excel date custom formate as date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have in excel cell date in this formate: `yyyymmdd` (e.g. `20141114`)

I tried formating it as but it always shows: `#################################################`

How to show it as `Nov 14, 2014` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried

> =DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"0000-00-00"))

It worked OK for me.

Update

> =TEXT(DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"0000-00-00")),"MMM DD, YYYY")

This is another solution in case we want to directly convet it to text

solution is from:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/28491-insert-formula-programatically.html

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the value `yyyymmdd` to a date `mm/dd/yyyy` in the cell (assuming) `A1` using a formula like this:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

The string will be now converted to DATE.
The desired formatting you can adjust over the context menu "Format cell", e.g. `Nov 14, 2014`